# MariaDB on Ubuntu - specific version

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

I want to install a specific version of MariaDB on Ubuntu for testing purposes.
I followed [this guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-mariadb-10-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-centos-7/); everything works well if I don't specify the version of the packages mariadb-server and mariadb-client.
When I try to specify the version, using the command

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server=1:10.4.12+maria~bionic mariadb-client=1:10.4.12+maria~bionic
```

I receive this error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.4 (>= 1:10.4.12+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.4 (>= 1:10.4.12+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, I changed the command to

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server=1:10.4.12+maria~bionic mariadb-server-10.4=1:10.4.12+maria~bionic mariadb-client=1:10.4.12+maria~bionic mariadb-client-10.4=1:10.4.12+maria~bionic
```

At the end of the install process, the right version seems to be installed

```
dave@pctest:~$ sudo apt policy mariadb-server
mariadb-server:
  Installed: 1:10.4.12+maria~bionic
  Candidate: 1:10.4.13+maria~bionic
```

but, entering the shell, the version is different

```
dave@pctest:~$ sudo mysql -u root
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 50
Server version: 10.4.13-MariaDB-1:10.4.13+maria~bionic-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> select version();
+--------------------------------------------+
| version()                                  |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 10.4.13-MariaDB-1:10.4.13+maria~bionic-log |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has this issue - there are a number of dependencies that are installed with mariadb which default to the latest version. These are the ones I had to install to get an older version of 10.4 working on ubuntu 20.04.2 (current version of mariadb is 10.4.19 - which is badly broken)

mariadb-client-10.4
mariadb-client-core-10.4
mariadb-common
mariadb-server-core-10.4
mysql-common
libmariadb3
mariadb-server-10.4
mariadb-server
mariadb-client
mariadb-backup

```
sudo apt install mariadb-client-10.4=1:10.4.17+maria~focal mariadb-client-core-10.4=1:10.4.17+maria~focal mariadb-common=1:10.4.17+maria~focal mariadb-server-core-10.4=1:10.4.17+maria~focal mysql-common=1:10.4.17+maria~focal  libmariadb3=1:10.4.17+maria~focal

sudo apt install mariadb-server-10.4=1:10.4.17+maria~focal mariadb-server=1:10.4.17+maria~focal mariadb-client=1:10.4.17+maria~focal mariadb-backup=1:10.4.17+maria~focal

sudo apt-mark hold mariadb-client-10.4 mariadb-client-core-10.4 mariadb-common mariadb-server-core-10.4 mysql-common libmariadb3 mariadb-server-10.4 mariadb-server mariadb-client mariadb-backup
```